# Is there a best practice regarding plural vs singular in entity naming?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

When naming entities in Visual Studio is there an accepted best practice for naming entities plural vs singular? Some examples I have seen name entities as plurals ...

> Customers vs. Customer

Is there a naming best practice for the navigation properties or relationship between entities?

Comment: Does `var customer = new Customers();` make sense?   Does `var accounts = person.Account;` make sense?

Comment: Indeed no .. that is why the examples were confusing to me (they were from an EF book). It would seem to me that the best use would be plural for a collection of objects. But I asked about best practices in case there was a better reason to use plural that I was not aware of.

Comment: I do not know of the examples you site, but my best guess would be that the pluralization of table names is more of a controversial topic.  When C# class names are born out of the table names, you might get generated C# class names that are pluralized.  However, in code-first (and in my opinion, at all times), your C# identifiers should make sense as C# identifiers.

Answer (score 5):

In ORM approach entities represent tables/views from database, and they take the exact same name by default. Many examples on the internet refer to `Northwind` database where tables are named like `Customers`, `Categories` etc. Taking into account that it is designed by Microsoft as a sample database and for educational purposes, plural naming convention sounds like a right way to go.

But the `Northwind` database dates back to SQL Server 2000 what was 15 years ago. As the SQL Server technology evolved, [sample databases were changing as well](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2013/09/09/revisited-the-story-of-pubs-northwind-and-adventureworks.aspx).

If you now look at [comparison](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124680%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) of [newer sample database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330) `AdventureWorks` with `Northwind`, you'll notice that names became singular. And I believe things like EntityFramework, Linq, Generics did play their part to make Microsoft rename tables in a singular way...Since there would be a lot of code in their educational code listings like following:

```
Customers customer = GetTopCustomer(); //errrr??
var customers = GetTopCustomers(); //collection this time.. or single item?
```

making code less human readable and extremely confusing.

Go the singular way :) 
Microsoft already did that with sample database.

Answer (score 4):

I am used to naming entities as singulars and tables as plurals. This makes most sense to me, because Customer is one and there can by many of them in Customers table.

As for navigation properties, I choose the name based on the same logic. If relationship links to more than one entity - go for plural.

Comment: What is the difference between an entity and a table in this context?